# EasyAdmin how to stay in edit form

Tags: list, view, edit, easyadmin

How to stay in edit form and not redirect to list view after saving entity ? I tried with actions but nothing seems to works.

Answer (score 3):

EasyAdmin has hard coded the redirect behavior in the "redirectToReferrer()" method in the AdminController.php. The order of the redirect rules is:

1. redirect to list if possible
2. from new|edit action, redirect to edit if possible
3. from new action, redirect to new if possible
4. else: redirect to homepage

What you want is to switch the second rule with the first rule.

You can do that by extending the AdminController.php and override the method "redirectToReferrer()" with your own logic and change the order of the redirect rules.

To be a bit less invasive you can override it in the following way:

```
/**
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
protected function redirectToReferrer()
{
    $refererAction = $this->request->query->get('action');

    // from new|edit action, redirect to edit if possible
    if (in_array($refererAction, array('new', 'edit')) && $this->isActionAllowed('edit')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('easyadmin', array(
            'action' => 'edit',
            'entity' => $this->entity['name'],
            'menuIndex' => $this->request->query->get('menuIndex'),
            'submenuIndex' => $this->request->query->get('submenuIndex'),
            'id' => ('new' === $refererAction)
                ? PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor()->getValue($this->request->attributes->get('easyadmin')['item'], $this->entity['primary_key_field_name'])
                : $this->request->query->get('id'),
        ));
    }

    return parent::redirectToReferrer();
}
```

This way, your rule is applied first and if it does not match the original redirect rules are applied. You can also add messages here to confirm that the entity was saved successfully.